# How can I clear out a list of select boxes after a particular element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a list of select boxes, all of which have the HTML class "attribute_select". This is a cascading list.

As I select each item, I use jQuery to populate and create one below the one just selected. One at a time.

But if a user jumps back up in the list and changes a select box, I want to not only re-grab the next box (no problem), but clear all of the boxes that are after it.

How can I write a jQuery selector to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/):

```
$(".attribute_select").change(function () {
    $(this).nextAll(".attribute_select").empty(); 
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7YPJt/)**.

Comment: SUPER, it stays confined to the siblings in the same div. Works!